# I think I broke my computer's boot loader

Tags: linux, windows-10, grub, bootloader, opensuse

I've downloaded Linux OpenSUSE a while back (as another partition, I run dual boot), which was going great for me. But I had to change my computer's boot order on BIOS from Windows' advanced reboot. After that, my computer would boot straight into Windows rather than Grub (that had actually happened before but I somehow fixed it, though I'm not sure how).

After a few days of that, I finally tried changing values on the Boot Loader software provided by OpenSUSE. I'm not entirely sure what it was, but I'm pretty sure I changed a value from 'Grub2 for EFI' to just 'Grub2', or something like that (may have been the other way around - it's been a few days - but I think that was it).

So, I restarted my computer *and it worke-* oh wait no it didn't. Just after reboot, my computer displayed the simple text 'No bootable device found'. Yay, I managed to break my computer *and it's not even the first time* but whatever.

I've tried asking for help at IT in my school, and searched it up on Google, but it only leads to dead ends mostly because either they assume it's a either problem with my hardware or I've wiped my system (neither of which is true, my computer and partitions are fine, I'm pretty sure I just messed up the boot files), or they advise me to use a bootable Windows USB, and I'd rather not pay to fix my computer if possible (seeing as Windows is proprietary that ain't happening if I go for the latter advice).

For extra information, I'm using an Ubuntu GNOME live USB for now, and I actually discovered the whole situation could've been avoided if I had realized that the operating system boot order can be changed in BIOS by pressing the 'Change value' key. So brownie points to my stupidity.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can still change the boot order in the BIOS, which loads before the OpenSUSE Boot Loader software, so you can boot into Windows. But if you want to boot Linux OpenSUSE......

Comment: Well, I've tried, but I can't change the 'OS Boot Manager' values. It acts as if there is no operating system at all.

Comment: Any possibility of a screenshot?

Comment: Sure. Though how do I go about posting the photos? I don't use Stack Exchange sites often.

Comment: You can upload your image to https://prnt.sc/ or http://imgur.com/

Comment: https://prnt.sc/gapl57 https://prnt.sc/gaplan https://prnt.sc/gapkt5 the initial screen, the BIOS settings and the boot manager settings respectively. In the second image, what differs from before is there's no triangle before the 'OS Boot Manager' that indicates there are multiple available values.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an amateur solution, but I had a lot of success using the [boot repair disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) to manage such situations. Basically, it will detect installed OSes and configure Grub for you.

Comment: I've tried burning boot-repair into a USB in the past, I had problems with connections. Today I tried running it from my live USB and it said I needed to enable a repository containing [grub-efi-amd64-signed] packages in the software sources of my OpenSUSE partition. I don't know how to do that, any advice?

Comment: No I don't know opensuse well enough. I have a [link here](https://forums.fedora-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=65385) (in french) of someone who had exactly the same error message as yours with fedora. He solved it by running a few commands. In the last message he says that the solution was to run the commands **while running the boot-repair disk**. It may work for you if you adapt the paths containing `fedora` to the correct paths in opensuse. These paths can be found if you search opensuse+efi on the web I think.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Linux installer disk, load it and then boot live CD. Then change the Grub2 value back to what it was (EFI is different to Legacy so thats why the error occurred) and it should work.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I've thought of that before. My OpenSUSE installer doesn't give any option to run from the live USB, and Ubuntu doesn't give me any way to edit the boot loader that I can see. The OpenSUSE installer USB lets me install it or run from hard disk I think (which is why I'm using Ubuntu right now). Any ideas on how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a lot of my Grub issues using https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/grub which has a lot of scenarios. Hopefully one of these methods can solve your problem.